# Is there a secure way to include an API Token in a desktop application? (JIRA integration)

Tags: api, oauth, token, jira

I'd like to add the ability to create JIRA issues from within a Unity game (C#), such as for submitting player feedback and bugs. I see various authentication approaches, from "basic" auth (just a raw UN and PW) to an Auth Token approach, to possibly some OAuth-based approach which I don't yet understand.

I've set up JIRA integration in web projects over the years, and it was fairly simple. I never had concerns over authentication, since the credentials to access JIRA were always stored within the web server's configuration. But with a deployed application (such as a game created in Unity), I don't understand if there's any secure/correct way to provide credentials to the application. It seems that it would be trivial for anyone to either inspect the code, or the memory of the running application, and extra the authorization credentials.

Is there a secure way for a desktop application (not connected to a central server) to authenticate against an API like JIRA's?